# How to remove text with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove the last two span tags with JavaScript. My code is

```
<h1 class='av-special-heading-tag'  itemprop="headline"  >Turning </h1><div class='special-heading-border'><div class='special-heading-inner-border' ></div></div></div>
<span class="av_font_icon avia_animate_when_visible av-icon-style-  av-no-color avia-icon-pos-center " style=""><span class='av-icon-char' style='font-size:20px;line-height:20px;' aria-hidden='true' data-av_icon='' data-av_iconfont='entypo-fontello' ></span></span>
<section class="av_textblock_section"  itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork" ><div class='avia_textblock '  style='font-size:20px; '  itemprop="text" ><p style="text-align: center;">
<span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
</div></section></div>
```

So want to remove

```
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
<span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
```

using Javascript.

Thank you.

I tried this but not working -

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 string.removeWord('colchester'); 
 </script>
```

Comment: I posted a question similar before using css but that wont work, so need to use javascript to remove it.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: If the css solution doesn't work then I don't see how a JS solution would be any different

Comment: I tried my own code but got stuck. So need some tiny bit of help. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this - <script type="text/javascript">
string.removeWord('colchester'); 
</script>

Comment: https://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (x < 2)` condition is how many records do you want to remove.

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll(".avia_textblock p span");

var x = 0;
for (var i = spans.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (x < 2) {
    spans[i].parentNode.removeChild(spans[i]);
    x++;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class='av-special-heading-tag' itemprop="headline">Turning </h1>
<div class='special-heading-border'>
  <div class='special-heading-inner-border'></div>
</div>
<span class="av_font_icon avia_animate_when_visible av-icon-style-  av-no-color avia-icon-pos-center " style=""><span class='av-icon-char' style='font-size:20px;line-height:20px;' aria-hidden='true' data-av_icon='' data-av_iconfont='entypo-fontello' ></span></span>
<section class="av_textblock_section" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">
  <div class='avia_textblock ' style='font-size:20px; ' itemprop="text">
    <p style="text-align: center;">
      <span style="color: #641380;">Mazak Nexus 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus QNT 200MY</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT200M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak SQT10M</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Nexus</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT10</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak QT8</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Colchester lathe</span><br />
      <span style="color: #641380;"> Mazak Harrison lathe</span></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For some reason its not working for me. This is the wesbite - http://www.penninetoolsaerospace.com/plant-list/

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested on chrome, firefox and edge and it is working.

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Can you see in a snippe that there are no last two spans? If you can, than maybe you changed class name or  structure. Make sure that `document.querySelectorAll(".avia_textblock p span")` is not empty. Try logging it in console and see what are the results. Maybe you have more elements with the same structure.

Comment: Yeah, its working on the snippet but not on my website that i am working on.

Comment: @java11 Ok I checked your site and it was as I expected. My answer was only a concept to show you how this works, but whatever. Just change this `document.querySelectorAll(".avia_textblock p span")` to this `document.querySelectorAll(".avia-builder-el-18 .avia_textblock p span")`

Comment: Beautiful. Saved me big time. Thank you so much. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let spans =  document.querySelectorAll('.avia_textblock p span');

for( i=spans.length-1; i>= spans.length-2; i-- ){
  spans[i].parentNode.removeChild(spans[i]);
}
```